# Permission denied creating new File Android Marshmallow after asking WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, permission-denied

My app is targeting SDK 23. I am trying to take a photo and I check if I got the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions. If it does not have these permissions it will request them using following line.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 12);
```

I check if the permission was accepted/allowed using the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method callback.

If it was accepted I use the following code to create a File.

```
// this code only gets called when permission was accepted by the user
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
```

Strangely enough I get following exception

```
error while creating file
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1004)
```

When I fully restart my app, the code just executes fine without any exceptions. I already tried to execute the code in another activity. It opens the activity when the permission was allowed, but than still I get that permission denied exception.

Am I doing anything wrong, could the problem be the emulator?

Comment: What do you mean "fully restart your app"? So after you restarted once and it worked, it doesn't work again and again?

Comment: @Gavriel When I allow/accept the permissions and I call the code which creates a file it throws that exception. When I fully close my app and restart it (permissions are now granted in settings) the code works just fine. Also when I reboot it after that. It is only not working when I request the permissions and call the code after permissions were granted.

Comment: maybe you should show us the code around `onRequestPermissionsResult`

Comment: have same problem how u resolved @PatrixWilliams